# Compress vendor JS libraries

Tags: javascript, angular, gulp

I'm trying to get a single `vendor.min.js` to reduce the number of external files to be loaded and to do so I have the following gulp task:

```
gulp.task('vendor-bundle', function() {
  gulp.src([
                'core-js/client/shim.min.js',
            'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
            'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
            'reflect-metadata/Reflect.js',
            'rxjs/**/*.js',
            'zone.js/dist/zone.js',
            '@angular/**/bundles/*.umd.js',
            '@ng-bootstrap/**/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js',
            'jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
            'bootstrap/dist/js/*.js',
            'tether/dist/**/tether.min.js',
  ],{cwd: "node_modules/**"})
  .pipe(concat('vendors.min.js'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

When I then try to run my Angular 2 application I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'window' has already been declared
    at vendors.min.js:1
(anonymous) @ vendors.min.js:1
app.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at app.js:1
(anonymous) @ app.js:1
```

I'm assuming that's because everything grouped together into a single file could cause definition conflicts?

I get another error in my `app.js` and I think that's because the `vendors.min.js` failed to load because of the error I'm getting.

Is there a way to remove duplicate definitions or a better way to concatenate the vendor files into a single one to reduce the resources to be fetched?

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line it has duplicate variables

```
 .pipe(concat('vendors.min.js'))
```

Comment: how then you get all JS files bundled into a single .js file if that was possible?

Comment: all js files are bundled with webpack.

Comment: That's right - I'm trying that now! Thanks for the help